# Simple Van de Graaff generator with friction only

Tags: electrostatics

I have found an interesting picture about different versions of the Van de Graaff generator:

[image]

(Source: http://www.coe.ufrj.br/~acmq/vdgself.jpg)

I know the Wimshurst system on the right but I have never seen the simple friction system on the left (neither as a real working device nor discussed in textbooks) and I not sure about the difference between the Holtz and the Toepler system. I didn't find any further information about this on the web.

How is the working principle and the difference of the three systems on the left (Friction, Holtz and Toepler)? Why is the charge source in the friction case not jaded very soon? What are the typical voltages you can achieve with the friction system only?

Is it correct that in the case of the friction system the blue roller on the bottom is stationary and the friction occurs between the band and the lower roller. But then the charge would be produced on the inner side of the band and not on the outer side.

Do you have any references about the details of the working principle of those specific Van de Graaff constructions and maybe also pictures or videos of working machines.

**Edit**

I found some interesting papers which show that it is a misconception that the charge accumulation on the top is due to the Faraday's ice pail principle but rather just as in Volta's condensing electroscope:

- http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/30/5/10.1119/1.1942016
- http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/22/5/10.1119/1.1933723
- http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/43/12/10.1119/1.10061

See my other question: [Is it true that it is a misconception that the Van de Graaf generator works with the Faraday's ice pail principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263932/is-it-true-that-it-is-a-misconception-that-the-van-de-graaff-generator-works-with)

However I think this doesn't change of how the rest of the machine works.

Comment: Robert Van de Graaff would likely prefer you spell his name correctly. But, as the operator of an original Van de Graaff accelerator, I see very small tweaks in the various 'systems' presented. It mainly has to do with how you charge, and if you try to charge going both up (+) and down (-). Actual belt/chain configurations have varied over time and by manufacturers.

Comment: No need to destroy the band and the roller by friction. The pressure of the band against the roller will do.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions here, but you are not offering any solutions of your own.  The site policy is to encourage you to do your own thinking and research (rather than expect others to do it all for you), and to show what effort you have made.  So please explain what **you** think the answers are, and point out any doubts which you have and the reasons for them.

Comment: in the friction system, + charge will come from inner and outer side. triboelectricity will remove + charge from blue roller thus making it negative. Then the negativity of the bottom roller will also attract positive ions from the comb to the outer surface, making the belt more positive.

Comment: Votages you can attain also depends a lot on the materials used.

Comment: the accumulated charges do not remain stationary in the belt or comb much longer but they are actually transferred through molecular ions from the comb to the lower belt, and also to the upper comb through "corona discharge". check http://amasci.com/emotor/belt.html

Comment: check also http://amasci.com/emotor/icepail.html . There seems to be no limit theoretically on the voltage it can attain.