# Is it true that it is a misconception that the Van de Graaff generator works with the Faraday's ice pail principle

Tags: electrostatics

I found some interesting papers which claim that it is a misconception that the charge accumulation on the top is due to the Faraday's ice pail principle but rather just as in Volta's condensing electroscope:

- http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/30/5/10.1119/1.1942016
- http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/22/5/10.1119/1.1933723
- http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/43/12/10.1119/1.10061

However those papers are pretty old any with very few citations. On every textbook I have seen so far the working principle is described as by Van de Graaff himself by using the Faraday ice pail principle. So what is the status today of which version is correct? Maybe both descriptions turned out to be misleading, so what is the correct theory of this machine today?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about history of science rather than physical concepts.

Comment: Please explain the close vote.

Comment: @CuriousOne This question **is** about physics, i.e. of what is the correct theory to describe the Van de Graaff generator.

Comment: You are not asking how the machines work, you are asking if it is appropriate to use old principles that we may be teaching in high school that no working physicist in the field will actually apply to the machine design.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41523/discussion-on-question-by-julia-is-it-true-that-it-is-a-misconception-that-the-v).

Comment: I think each method is correct because they focus on different aspects of the apparatus.   Van de Graaff says that if the location of the various parts is constant, then the maximum voltage depends on the breakdown voltage of the sphere, while Simon says that if you move the location of the parts, the maximum voltage  depends on the distance between the electrodes.   Both are correct!